# Send command after Keywait, but only if the given time is right?

Tags: autohotkey

So this sequence resets itself after 1.5 sec (t:=1500) which means if i dont hit the left mouse button for 1.5 sec it always sends A. Otherwise it sends the next letter after each click.

*I want to further tweak this code with these other functions which are:*

- If i let go the LButton between 0 - 0.3 seconds, it sends 0 resets the sequence
- If i let go the LButton between 0.3 - 0.6 seconds, it dont sends 0 continue the sequence
- If i let go the LButton between 0.6 - 1.2 seconds, it sends 0 resets the sequence
- If i let go the LButton between 1,2 - above seconds, it dont sends 0 continue the sequence

*The zero key is a function in the game thats why i need after LMB keywait!*
.

```
global s:=0, c:=0, t:=1500


Seqkeys(params*) { 
    global s, c, t
    max := params.MaxIndex()
    (A_TickCount-s<=t && (c+=1)<=max) ? c : c:=1
    s := A_TickCount
    return params[c]
}


*LButton::
        Send % Seqkeys("A","B")
        KeyWait, LButton
        Send, 0
Return
```

- i want to implement this function somehow to the 0 key. It means if i hit the zero key, it resets the sequence always to the first letter (A). but i dont know how to make this function work inside the "*LButton::"

> ```
> *0::
>       c := 1
>       s := 0
> Return
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
#SingleInstance Force
#UseHook
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SendMode Input

Global nCount := 1, nTimeOut := 1500

Seqkeys(params*) {
    Local
    Global nCount, nTimeOut
    If ( (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 300) and (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < nTimeOut) ) {
        sChar := params[nCount]
        nCount := (nCount == params.MaxIndex()) ? 1 : (nCount + 1)
        return sChar
    }
    return 0
}


*LButton::
KeyWait, LButton
Send % Seqkeys("A","B","C")
Return
```

If not, you should try to rephrase your question, because it's not easy to understand. I have no idea what you want in your last paragraph, for example.

Comment: thx for the help. i mean in the game the 0 number has got an action applied to it. but i dont want that action to activate when the time betweens are not correct. so if  i let go the LMB between 0.3 - 1.5 sec it shoudnt send 0. but when it sends (if i let go the LMB before 0.3 sec or after 1.5 sec) it should apply this  "c := 1 s := 0" to the 0 key to able reset the sequence. right now your code is not working the original works better even without the reset function. :( 0 number always should come after the letters like this if its active: A0, B0, C0 like this.

Comment: but of course if the 0 number is not activated the seqence always should look like this: A, B, C.

Comment: @bubyoz Sorry, but this hasn't cleared anything up for me. For example, how do you expect to ever see `B0` and `C0`, if letting LMB go before 0.3s or after 1.5s is supposed to reset the sequence with the `c := 1` assignment? Wouldn't it always be `A0`?

Comment: you are right my calculations were wrong. i was plain stupid. :D sry! these are my new calculations: If i let go the LMB between " 0s - 0.3s reset the sequence, 0.3s - 0.6s continue the sequence, 0.6s - 1.2s reset the sequence, 1.2s - above continue! i believe this is the right calculation ill update the post too! thx

Comment: help me please if u have the time thanks .D no rush here :D